# Is there a standard format for applications to log trace-level information?

Tags: debugging, logging, format

I have an application that does complex evaluations on a request basis.  We have options to turn on "trace" logging where we log a substantial amount of business information.

But it's very ad hoc in format.  It is hierarchical and quite long.

We are searching on a format that can be viewed with tools.  Potentially we may want our users to be able to use this log-viewing tool.

It seems outside of what i see for other log viewers.  They are mostly for viewing events and not long debug/trace information.

Any suggestions on a standard or format?

today we have a very ad hoc format that uses indentation to show nesting